# R: Recursive function within function

Tags: r

For my likelihood function, the denominator is defined by the recursive function `recurseG` for each observation (1:N).

If I loop over the function, everythings ok.

When I embed the procedure inside my main (likelihood)function, things get weird. xG, which is the input for recurseG, goes missing. Never seen that before, any ideas what the problem is? Cheers.

```
recurseG <- function(T,S){ # xG externally defined
  if (S==0) return(1)
  if (S>T) return(0)
  else return (Recall(T-1, S) + Recall(T-1, S-1)*xG[T])
}

# define for replication
N=10; T=3
x <- matrix(rnorm(N*T),N,T)
tG <- rep(T,N)
sG <- sample(rep(0:T,T), N)

## standalone

denom <- rep(NA, N)
for (i in 1:N){
  xG <- x[i,]
  denom[i] <- recurseG(tG[i], sG[i])
} 

## inside function

rm(xG) # will produce "not found"

fout <- function(x){
  denom <- rep(NA, N)
  for (i in 1:N){
    xG <- x[i,]
    denom[i] <- recurseG(tG[i], sG[i])
  } 
  return(denom)
}

denom
fout(x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has got nothing to do with recursion. You simply define `xG` *inside* your `fout` function. However, `recurseG` is defined *outside* it. The visibility of `xG` is constrained to the scope it is defined in, thus it is not visible in `recurseG`.

To solve the problem, simply pass `xG` to `recurseG` as a parameter:

```
recurseG <- function(T, S, xG) {
    if (S == 0) return(1)
    if (S > T) return(0)
    else return(Recall(T - 1, S, xG) + Recall(T - 1, S - 1, xG) * xG[T])
}
```